# Unable to run C coded DLL in Excel VBA

Tags: c, excel, vba, dll, mingw-w64

I have a Windows 10 64-bits, Office 2013 32-bits and using MinGW64.

I followed instructions from https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/

I checked other answers threads in stackoverflow without success.

When I run Excel VBA code I get the follow error: "Run-Time error 48: File not found", but the file is in the folder and the folder has PATH reference.

I have the Add.c with follow code:

```
#include "add.h"
#include <windows.h>

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
  switch (fdwReason)
  {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      /* Code path executed when DLL is loaded into a process's address space. */
      break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
      /* Code path executed when a new thread is created within the process. */
      break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
      /* Code path executed when a thread within the process has exited *cleanly*. */
      break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      /* Code path executed when DLL is unloaded from a process's address space. */
      break;
  }

  return TRUE;
}

int ADDCALL Add(int a, int b)
{
  return (a + b);
}

/* Assign value to exported variables. */
int foo = 7;
int bar = 41;
```

The follow Add.h code:

```
/* add_var.h

   Declares a function and variables to be imported by our application, and
   exported by our DLL.
*/

/* You should define ADD_EXPORTS *only* when building the DLL. */
#ifdef ADD_EXPORTS
  #define ADDAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define ADDAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

/* Define calling convention in one place, for convenience. */
#define ADDCALL __cdecl

/* Make sure functions are exported with C linkage under C++ compilers. */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

/* Declare our Add function using the above definitions. */
ADDAPI int ADDCALL Add(int a, int b);

/* Exported variables. */
extern ADDAPI int foo;
extern ADDAPI int bar;

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // __cplusplus defined.
#endif
```

And the follow VBA code to test:

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Add Lib "C:\exceladd2\AddLib.dll" (ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer

Sub Test()
    Call MsgBox(Add(4, 5))
End Sub
```

The follow code was compiled with MinGW64 without errors or warnings:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-8.1.0 -c -o add.o add.c -D ADD_EXPORTS
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-8.1.0 -o AddLib.dll add.o -shared -s -Wl,--subsystem,windows,--kill-at
```

The follow is the result from dependencies check from the library: https://pasteboard.co/J4zegPO.jpg

I tried to compile with gcc 32 bits and other versions of gcc 64-bits and got the same error 48 in Excel.

On the past I was able to run similar DLL compiled with gcc 32-bits in a Windows 7 32-bits with Office 2010 32-bit without any trouble. Ran Excel VBA with and without PtrSafe without result.

Is there anything wrong with code or compile?

Do you know any software to troubleshoot DLLs?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using C rather than Visual Studio Community and the C# compiler.

Comment: No special reason. I use C/C++ mostly to have performance in math calculations and microcontroller programming. Normally I work in Code::blocks or Notepad++ to build console applications. Just to add more information: I tried to build a similar DLL with Code blocks templates, but it did not work. Main issue with DLL is the limited capability to troubleshooting.

Comment: Seems something changed since last time I built a 32-bits DLL. On that time it was straight forward. Now I do not know what is happen, but seems I am missing something.